# Install PHP-7.3 with phpbrew on OS X 10.15.7 (aka OSX14) fails

Tags: php, macos, phpbrew

Installation of PHP-7.3 with phpbrew on OS X 10.15.7 (Catalina):

> Error: Make failed:
> The last 5 lines in the log file:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/dirent.h:110:1: note: 'readdir_r' declared here

> int readdir_r(DIR *, struct dirent *, struct dirent **) __DARWIN_INODE64(readdir_r);

> ^

> 1 error generated.

> make: *** [main/reentrancy.lo] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade the Command Line Tools to the version for Xcode 11.5 (or 11.x).
You can download them here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

(I also installed Xcode 11.7 but that won't fix the issue)

I've found this solution here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/61820